# RDP works over Internet, not locally

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop

I've set up an RDP connection to a Windows 8.1 Pro client via Internet (Dyn), which works fine. However, over the local network I can't connect to the machine via RDP.

Relevant information:

- I can RDP into other computers on the network so it probably is not a router issue.
- RDP into the client works from other computers.
- There is no additional firewall installed. Virus scanner is Defender (built into Windows).
- Ping to the machine does not work (Request timed out).
- The client is on Hyper-V, but I can RDP into another Hyper-V client on the same server.
- Both clients are on subnet mask (255.255.255.0) and share the same standard gateway (192.168.178.1).

I have done all of the following without success:

- Completely disabled the Windows firewall for testing.
- Verified the IP address.
- Used the hostname instead of the IP in mstsc.
- Tried all user accounts set up on the remote machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the subnet mask on both the system to which you wish to connect and the one from which you wish to connect to verify they are in the same [subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork)? You could also try installing a [packet sniffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer), such as [Wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) or [SmartSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html), which are free, on the systems.

Comment: @moonpoint subnet masks are the same. Have installed Wireshark, but what would I look for?

Comment: Can you please try to do `nslookup <machine>` from both within and outside the local network? Do you get similar results? What happens when you try to ping the IP addresses from the nslookup?

Comment: @cdavid locally I get the correct IP, from outside I get the dynamic IP provided by my Internet Provider. Ping local --> timeout, ping outside --> no packets lost.

Comment: I have no idea why, but it works now locally from the one computer as well.